# Centos 7 network issue

Tags: networking, firewall, centos7, telnet

I have a Centos 7 server behind a Dell sonicwall I have configured the sonicwall to allow certain services and this seems to work fine. However I can't telnet to some ports. I have added Wireshark to Centos 7 to verify packets on said ports are arriving which they do. I can telnet to port 22 for ssh and that works fine internally and externally. My VNC service works internally from another machine too. However ports 80,443 and a service port I wanted 2526 do not work. The traffic is hitting the server so I know the Sonicwall is fine. However in Wireshark I get this line in red

`28632  1398.805571570  192.168.x.x x.x.x.x TCP 54  telnet > 26354 [RST, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=0 Len=0.` This entry is going back out of my server (via NAT) to the originating source of the telnet. So handshaking I guess in order to connect. I can telnet out of my CentOS 7 server to another network so I know I have connectivity out.

IF I run `ss -tnlp` I just see listening on ports for SSH and VNC.

I have disabled SELInux (not sure if that was a good idea or not!) and I have added my rules for the ports correctly I believe ( as I managed the VNC server one for instance)

I used the usual firewall-cmd commands to add my rules and I used the permanent switch as well.

I even tried this

```
firewall-cmd --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter INPUT 0 -p tcp --dport 2526 -j ACCEPT
```

In order to bypass the firewall for that port altogether and yet still no joy.

My centos 7 server has 3 NIC's setup 2 of which are for internal use i.e. on 10.x.x.x networks. My default gateway has a 192.168.x.x network the same as my em1 default interface. The internal address is Natted out via the sonicwall to an IP which of course I can ping internally and externally.

My assumption is the network inbound is fine but something is amiss going back out.

At this point what would a 'real' Linux expert do next ( aside of recommending I do a networking course at college and come back to it!) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Uhhh, I might just be misreading your question but your comment:

> *"IF I run `ss -tnlp` I just see listening on ports for SSH and VNC"*

explains why can't connect to ports 80 and/or 443: there is simply nothing there to accept an incoming connection... Either start a webserver or enable a simple listener with  `[sudo] nc -l -p 80` or `openssl s_server -accept 443 [options]` if you need a TLS/SSL listener (check man s_server for options).

Comment: No that is fine you are reading correctly my intention initially is to be able to telnet into the server on 2526 I would imagine there wouldn't be a listener. I presumed add firewall rule and test all good. However that hasn't been the case. I also assumed I could telnet to port 80 as well but perhaps not. I guess I will have to run something on my service port to confirm its running then I guess.